# Closure traversal or iterator for code clarity and performance?

Tags: c++, performance, oop, iterable

In the following example, I have a 2D matrix class and would like to iterate over the neighbours of a particular element. Two approaches are possible:

- Use iterators
- Use closure with lambda expression

I wonder which of the two approaches is better for performance and readabilty. In my naive opinion, the iterator is way more boilerplate.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Matrix {
    using array = std::vector<T>;
    using size = std::size_t;
    array data;
    size rows_;
    size cols_;

   public:
    Matrix(size rows, size cols)
        : data(cols * rows), rows_{rows}, cols_{cols} {}

    T &operator()(size row, size col) { return data[row * cols_ + col]; }

    const T &operator()(size row, size col) const {
        return data[row * cols_ + col];
    }

    int rows() const { return rows_; }
    int cols() const { return cols_; }

    void traverse(std::function<void(T &)> f, size row, size col) {
        for (auto &[rd, cd] : neighbours_delta) {
            int r = row + rd, c = col + cd;
            if (r >= 0 && r < rows_ && c >= 0 && c < cols_) f((*this)(r, c));
        }
    }

    typename array::iterator begin() { return data.begin(); }
    typename array::iterator end() { return data.end(); }

    auto neighbours(size row, size col) {
        return NeighbourIterator(row, col, *this);
    }

   protected:
    std::pair<int, int> neighbours_delta[8] = {
        {-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}};

    struct NeighbourIterator {
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T *;
        using reference = T &;

        NeighbourIterator(size row, size col, Matrix<T> &m, int neighbour = 0)
            : row{row}, col{col}, m{m}, neighbour{neighbour} {}

        auto get_delta() const { return m.neighbours_delta[neighbour]; }

        bool exists() {
            auto [rd, cd] = get_delta();
            int r = row + rd, c = col + cd;
            return r >= 0 && r < m.rows_ && c >= 0 && c < m.cols_;
        }

        T &get_neighbor() const {
            auto [rd, cd] = get_delta();
            return m(row + rd, col + cd);
        }

        reference operator*() const { return get_neighbor(); }
        pointer operator->() { return get_neighbor(); }
        NeighbourIterator &operator++() {
            do {
                neighbour++;
            } while (neighbour < 8 && !exists());

            return *this;
        }
        NeighbourIterator operator++(int) {
            NeighbourIterator tmp = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return tmp;
        }
        auto begin() { return NeighbourIterator(row, col, m, 0); }
        auto end() { return NeighbourIterator(row, col, m, 8); }

        friend bool operator==(const NeighbourIterator &a,
                               const NeighbourIterator &b) {
            return a.neighbour == b.neighbour;
        };
        friend bool operator!=(const NeighbourIterator &a,
                               const NeighbourIterator &b) {
            return a.neighbour != b.neighbour;
        };

       private:
        Matrix<T> &m;
        size row, col;
        int neighbour;
    };
};

int main() {
    Matrix<int> m(10, 10);
    std::fill(m.begin(), m.end(), 0);

    m.traverse([](int &el) { el = 0; }, 5, 5);
    for (auto &el : m.neighbours(8, 8)) el = 8;
}
```

Comment: the design is a little confusing.An iterator that has begin and end is somewhat strange

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number So it would be better to have `neighbours` that return an object of a dummy intermediate object that has `begin` and `end` which returns an instance of `NeighbourIterator`... It is even more cumbersome.

Comment: why more cumbersome? Its the same your are doing now with less confusing names.

Comment: Declaring an iterator in C++ takes a lot of lines